# Replace new version of Infragistics controls with old version of Infragistics controls

Tags: desktop-application, infragistics

I am using Infragistics Win Controls for my windows desktop application. At present I am using 8.3 Version of Infragistics Controls. Now I want to use New Version 12.1.

Can I replace and add these controls in my project? I don't know how to do this and change my old version to new version of Infragistics control in existing controls.

Can any one give me some idea regarding the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To upgrade the controls you need to change the Infragistics references to be the new version of the assembly.  While you can do this manually, Infragistics also provides a [Version Utility](http://help.infragistics.com/NetAdvantage/WinForms/Current/CLR2.0/?page=Win_Upgrading_a_Project_to_NetAdvantage_Windows_Forms_11.1_%28and_above%29_Using_Version_Utility.html) that will help you with this.